# Opening other app from cordova plugin fails

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-intent, cordova-plugins

I want to open the Play Books app from my Cordova application using a book's web reader url. This code worked fine until recently:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.books", "com.google.android.apps.books.app.ReadingActivity"));
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Now I receive this error:

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.apps.books/com.google.android.apps.books.app.ReadingActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

AFAIK I dont have to declare activities from other apps that I want to call. Am I right?

Is there any Android or other update released recently that could have caused this error?

Comment: They probably changed their main activity name so it doesn't find it anymore

Comment: Indeed they did. Now the activity is called com.google.android.apps.play.books.app.ReadingActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the activity has been changed to com.google.android.apps.**play**.books.app.ReadingActivity.